# Jackknife in logistic regression

Tags: r, glm

I'm interested into apply a Jackknife analysis to in order to quantify the uncertainty of my coefficients estimated by the logistic regression. I´m using a glm(family=’binomial’) because my independent variable is in 0 - 1 format.

My dataset has 76000 obs, and I'm using 7 independent variables plus an offset. The idea involves to split the data in let’s say 5 random subsets and then obtaining the 7 estimated parameters by dropping one subset at a time from the dataset. Then I can estimate uncertainty of the parameters.

I understand the procedure but I'm unable to do it in R.

This is the model that I'm fitting:

```
glm(f_ocur ~ altitud + UTM_X + UTM_Y + j_sin + j_cos + temp_res + pp +
             offset(log(1/off)), data = mydata, family = 'binomial')
```

Does anyone have an idea of how can I make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Jackknifing a logistic regression model is incredibly inefficient. But an easy time intensive approach would be like this:

```
Formula <- f_ocur~altitud+UTM_X+UTM_Y+j_sin+j_cos+temp_res+pp+offset(log(1/off))
coefs <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i)
  coef(glm(Formula, data=mydata[-i, ], family='binomial'))
)
```

This is your matrix of leave-one-out coefficient estimates. The covariance matrix of this matrix estimates the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates.

A significant time improvement could be had by using `glm`'s  workhorse function, `glm.fit`. You can go even farther by linearizing the model (use one-step estimation, limit `niter` in the Newton Raphson algorithm to one iteration only, using Jackknife SEs for the one-step estimators are still robust, unbiased, the whole bit...)

Comment: Hi ashkan, care to elaborate on why the questioner's use of jackknifing is a bad idea? (...on a level that a stats noob might understand?) Purely based on efficiency, or are there other reasons? I guess the same must apply to bootstrapping? Thanks!

Comment: +1 joran, the advantage of bootstrap (also easy to implement) is that it incorporates the influence of clusters of high leverage observations in the uncertainty estimates. This is particularly useful in data with unspecified clusters like household analyses.